# ROS compatible sensors

Tags: ros, 3dcamera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello buddies!

I was wondering if all sensors and computer peripherals could be used with ROS. Which sensors are compatible with nodes? Can we write nodes for all kinds of devices? And in particular, how can I use a random USB Camera in my robot? (if I had one)

Thank you in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256310/ros-compatible-sensors/) by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on ROS Answers with karma: 30 on 2017-03-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Please see [wiki/Sensors](http://wiki.ros.org/Sensors) for a start.

That is not an exhaustive list (read: there are tons more sensors that have ROS drivers), but should give you an idea.

To quickly find out if something is usable with ROS: use Google, keywords: `ros $name_of_your_sensor`.

> And in particular, how can I use a random USB Camera in my robot?

Most (if not all these days) USB cameras are [uvc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/USB_video_device_class) compatible, meaning that your Linux distro will most likely be compatible with them OOTB. Packages like [libuvc_camera](http://wiki.ros.org/libuvc_camera) and [usb_cam](http://wiki.ros.org/usb_cam) should be able to interface with such cameras.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-03-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-07**:
Note btw: even if there is no *hw specific* ROS node/pkg directly available for something you'd like to use, there may be one that is compatible with an entire *hardware class* (like the "uvc compatible usb cams").

**Comment by [Rai](https://answers.ros.org/users/29580/rai/) on 2017-03-07**:
thank you for the answer, can I use arduino (for example) to get the reading from a sensor and then upload it to ros? How does it work?

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2017-03-07**:\

> can i use arduino

yes, take a look at [rosserial](http://wiki.ros.org/rosserial) and / or [ros_arduino_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_arduino_bridge).